# How to sort a hash with duplicate key?

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash

I have a hash

`h = {}
h.compare_by_identity
h[2.51] = 1
h1[2.51] = 2`

Edit: `h1[2.51] = 2` should be `h[2.51] = 2`

it is ok with duplicate key. But when i use

```
Hash[h.sort]
```

it return only one value with key like

```
{2.51=>2}
```

is there any way to get the two values from the hash in sorted order?

Comment: if we use h.compare_by_identity then it contains duplicate key.

Comment: @Muktadir as Cary stated, you cannot have duplicate keys. You are assigning different hashes in your code-example. you are calling `h[2.51] = 1` and  `h1[2.51] = 2`

Comment: I assume the second assignment to `h1` is a typo is supposed to be `h`?

Comment: thank you @karlingen. opps... it was may typing mistake. now it is ok.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that you originally had `h1[2.51] = 2`, but you should not have changed that to `h[2.51] = 2`, as you did, without indicating that it is an edit, for a silent edit like that can render answers (here @karlingen's) or comments non-sensical. It's better to leave what you have and add text, making clear that what you are adding is an edit (e.g., Edit: `h1[2.51] = 2` should be `h[1.51] = 2`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it can't be done with floats, turn them into strings:

```
h = {}
h.compare_by_identity
h[2.51.to_s] = 2
h[2.51.to_s] = 1
p h.sort # => [["2.51", 1], ["2.51", 2]]
```

Comment: steenslag thank you so much... :) i think it is that what i need. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with ruby version 2.0 the key `2.51` is actually the same object (because of ruby internal caching) in both assignments. Try to output `2.51.object_id` for both cases and it will output the same id.